# How come assigning the value of variable to an AngularJS function is making the variable undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my Main Controller:

```
angular.module("HomePageApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "BaseService", function($http, $window, BaseService) {

        var self = this;

        self.posts = BaseService.fetch['YPosts']();
        self.logoutUser = function() {
            console.log(self.posts);
            BaseService.logout();
        };

    }]);
```

and this is my BaseService (some return objects are not shown for simplicity sake):

```
angular.module("BaseApp", [])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    }])

    .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }])

    .factory("BaseService", ["$http", "$window", function($http, $window) {
        var cerrorMessages = [];
        var posts = {};
        return {

        fetch: {
            XPosts: function() {
                $http.get('/postsX/')
                .then(function(response) {
                    posts = response.data;
                }, function(response) {
                    posts = {};
                    cerrorMessages = BaseService.accessErrors(response.data);
                });
                return posts;
            },

            YPosts: function() {
                $http.get('/postsY')
                .then(function(response) {
                    posts = response.data;
                    console.log(posts);
                    return posts;
                }, function(response) {
                    console.log('here');
                    posts = {};
                    cerrorMessages = BaseService.accessErrors(response.data);
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

When I log `posts` in my `BaseService`, it consists of objects. But when I click `logout` (which logs `posts` again), it says that it is undefined. Any idea why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a return statement only returns from the scope of its function. Javascript tends to encourage passing callbacks to long running functions so that the code doesn't block other activities. If you want the value of posts once the get request is resolved, have `YPosts` take a callback:

```
        YPosts: function(callback) {
            $http.get('/postsY')
            .then(function(response) {
                posts = response.data;
                console.log(posts);
                callback(posts);
            }, function(response) {
                console.log('here');
                posts = {};
                cerrorMessages = BaseService.accessErrors(response.data);
            });
        }
```

**Edit:**

Call YPosts like this:

```
BaseService.fetch.YPosts(function(posts) {
    self.posts = posts;
});
// however note that the callback will not be executed until the request completes
// so `self.posts === undefined` out here
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying `callback is not a function` when I try this code. Any idea why?

Comment: sounds like you aren't passing a callback argument to `YPosts`. see edit

Answer (score 1):

The `then()` in your `YPosts` is a Promise callback, and returning a value there isn't the same as returning a value from `YPosts`. What you do in `XPosts` also won't work: you `return posts` in `XPosts` itself, but the value will not have been set yet, because in most cases the `$http.get` won't have called the then/success callback yet.

You could introduce another callback as in lyjackal's answer, or just use the existing one in the right place:

```
       YPosts: function() {
            return $http.get('/postsY')
       }
```

and

```
    var self = this;
    BaseService.fetch.YPosts().then(
        function(response) { self.posts = response.data; },
        function(response) { ... } // error handler
    );

    self.logoutUser = function() {
        console.log(self.posts);
        BaseService.logout();
    };
```

Beware, though, that if the `logoutUser` function is called before `YPosts` is complete, the `console.log(self.posts)` will again show `undefined`.

Comment: And do I return `posts` or return `self.posts`? In both cases, I am still getting `undefined` on the front-end when I click "logout" :/

Comment: @Kenny Correction to my above comment, if I return `posts` it gives an error saying `posts is not defined` but when I return `self.posts` then it is still `undefined` when I click the "logout" button. On my front-end, I am also looping over `self.posts` but nothing is showing up (meaning it is empty).

Comment: Ah indeed, I see what you mean. My answer is wrong. I'll change it ;-) Updated! That's it, right?

Comment: I have `return posts` right after my `console.log()` function :)

Comment: Meh. :-) (It was late ;-)). But I know the answer now - assuming that your `XPosts` also doesn't work.